# how to pass a struct of array to function

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I have this piece of code that I would like to turn into a function, I can not figure out how to do it, this code reads the authors from files, and puts them in an array. I noticed that the main file is getting too big so I have to streamline it. nartisti is the number of artists actually contained in the file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>
#define max 30            
#define maxu 20            
#define sessomu 6          
#define sessom 6          

struct cantanti
{
int id;
char nome[max],cognome[max],nazionalita[max],sesso[sessom],genere[max];
};
struct cantanti arrayc[100];

 case 1:
    {
        system("cls");//pulisco lo schermo

        FILE *fp;//puntatore a file
        int nartisti;//variabile per contare quanti artisti ci sono nel file
        fp=fopen("artisti.dat","r");//apro il file artisti in modalita' lettura
        fscanf(fp,"%d",&nartisti);//leggo da file il numero degli artisti presenti
        int i=0;//azzero la variabile per ciclare il contatore
        printf("  _____________________________________________________________________________________\n");
        printf("|| %-5s || %-12s || %-12s || %-15s || %-4s || %-12s ||\n","<ID>","<NOME>","<COGNOME>","<NAZIONALITA'>","<SESSO>","<GENERE>");
        printf("||_______||______________||______________||_________________||_________||______________||\n");

        while(i!=nartisti)
        {
            //scansioni gli artisti da file, gli inserisco in un array di cantanti e li visualizzo a schermo
            fscanf(fp,"%d %s %s %s %s %s",&arrayc[i].id,arrayc[i].nome,arrayc[i].cognome,arrayc[i].nazionalita,arrayc[i].sesso,arrayc[i].genere);
            printf("||%-6d || %-12s || %-12s || %-15s || %-7s || %-12s ||\n",arrayc[i].id,arrayc[i].nome,arrayc[i].cognome,arrayc[i].nazionalita,arrayc[i].sesso,arrayc[i].genere);
            printf("||_______||______________||______________||_________________||_________||______________||\n");
            i++ ;
        }
        //mi dice quanti cantanti sono stati letti
        printf("**************************|    Sono stati letti %d autori dal file      |****************\n",nartisti);
        printf("***************************\\___________________________________________/ ****************\n\n");
        fclose(fp);//chiudo il file

        system("pause");
        system("cls");//pulisce lo schermo
    }
    break;
```

Comment: Where is the function in your code?

Comment: I would like you to help me to write it please, from what I understand I should pass only the array and the file, but I can not do it

Comment: Well first you should decide what code you want in the function as you've started off with a `case` statement and the code is also printing out the array too - if it's a function for reading, it should just be doing just that.

Answer (score -1):

you first need to declare the function

```
void readAuthors()
```

or return the array

```
struct readAuthors()
```

then just write the function as normal

```
void/struct readAuthors(){ 
    <code>
}
```

after that you can you can call the function

```
readAuthors()
or
array = readAuthors
```

i hope this helps

Comment: You cant return an array in C.

Comment: void readAuthors() - I should write it before the main void/struct readAuthors(){ 
    <code>
} After main - struct readAuthors() in the main?

Comment: `struct readAuthors()` is missing the name of the struct and would only return one of them